# XSLT on each looped node, output number of preceding nodes containing a specific element

Tags: xslt, count, nodes

Given this XML

```
<Employee>
  <Record>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Amount>10</Amount>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Amount>0</Amount>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Amount>0</Amount>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Amount>20</Amount>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <Amount>50</Amount>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <ID>6</ID>
    <Amount>0</Amount>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <ID>7</ID>
    <Amount>40</Amount>
  </Record>
</Employee>
```

Using XSLT 1.0, I want the output to be as follows:

```
Zero amount node: 0
Zero amount node: 0
Zero amount node: 1
Zero amount node: 2
Zero amount node: 2
Zero amount node: 2
Zero amount node: 3
```

I want to use a `for-each` and loop in the `Record` nodes and on each iteration, output the number of preceding nodes that contained zero `Amount`.

My XSLT:

```
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="Employee/Record">

    <xsl:variable name="amount-so-far" select=". | preceding-sibling::Record"/>
    <xsl:variable name="amount-so-far-not-zero" select="$amount-so-far[not('0' = preceding-sibling::Record/Amount)]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count($amount-so-far-not-zero)"/>

    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the problem you have encountered? Please show your XSLT transform so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Actually, its the first time that I'm posting a question. I have added the XSLT now. 
Next time, I'll make sure to post all the materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XSLT to get your desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="Employee">
    <xsl:for-each select="Record">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Zero amount node: ', count(preceding-sibling::Record[Amount='0']))"/><xsl:text>

      </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```